# Git push and committing on the remote confusion?

Tags: git

I have a local repo and a remote SSH repo. I am the sole users of these. I use the remote as my backup. I have couple branching in my local. When push them(one of the branch) it seems to work fine, but the issue I have is that when I open up the remote repo I see that there is one commit waiting after a push, and the second is that I do not see my local changes although Git says that everything went fine and the remote says that there has been modifier files.

So I am wondering if that is how push work really? Do I have to commit every push on the remote manually? I mostly want to use it back up, so I want an automated way, ie the remote accepts the push and does the commit there.

And the second question is that why am I not seeing the changes I have done on the remote? I have pushed successfully from local to remote, committed successfully on the remote, but the file is the old version. I am not sure if it is a network issue or some other thing.  Did  anyone else have similar issues?

The remote is Linux samba, and the local is Windows 7.

thanks

Comment: What do you mean “open up the remote repo”? Going to the remote server and `cd`ing into the directory? Is your remote a bare repository?

Comment: Do you realize that your remote repo should be a bare repo (see https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html )? Pushing into a non-bare repo will do funny things to it, as the working copy will not be updated.

Comment: sleske I did not know it, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have to work in the following way (assuming that you have a local clone of the repository):

- create a local branch: `git branch <new_branch_name>` and switch to it: `git checkout <new_branch_name>`
- push the branch to the remote repository: `git push -u origin <new_branch_name>`
- after modifying something, commit the changes: `git commit -a -m <commit_message>`
- push the change to the remote repository: `git push`

In order to retrieve the changes made by somebody else in the remote repo, you have to do a `git pull`.